# Problem opening downloaded zip file using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios, blob

I am trying to open a downloaded a zip file sent to me against a `GET` request. I am using `axios` for my api requests.

**PROBLEM**

File is downloaded. But I am not able to extract or open it. Empty archive issue.

**What I am using?**

This is my response handler:

```
const data = response.data
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));

const link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute("download", `report.zip`);

document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
```

1. The API works fine. Tested with `Postman`. Able to download and work with files within that zip.
2. The above code works fine for `csv` file type.

I suspect that `Blob` thing. Please share what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but maybe you're just missing the `type` for the blob. This is the function I'm using to download files with Ajax. There's also a special path for Internet Explorer/Edge, because it will block the synthetic link click.

```
const downloadFile = (data, filename, type = "application/zip") => {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type })
  if(navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob,filename)
  } else {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = url
    link.setAttribute('download', filename)
    document.body.appendChild(link)
    link.click()
    document.body.removeChild(link)
  }
}
```

So you can use it in your code like this:

```
const data = response.data
downloadFile(data, "report.zip")
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and found the solution.
You have to set `responseType: 'blob'` in your axios request. The default axios responseType is json, which is suitable for formats like csv or text files but not for zip files.
I hope this helps!